# how to solve this scenario using sql query?

Tags: sql

I have a table with the values

```
bill_amt days month
250        28  Feb
300        31  mar
500        30  apr.
```

My total debt amount is 700.

Now the problem is I need to add the bill_amts to get my total debt amount.

Ex:
for apr-> I have 500 as my bill amt and days as 30. my total debt is 700. I need 200 more to clear my debt. so I ll take 200 from the march .

But march has 300 and days as 31. So I need to take 200 alone from it and need to calculate the appropriate date only. Ex: (200/300 *31)- this will give me, no of days for march for the amount 200.

Now I need to add up the total no of days in apr and the newly found no of days in march to get my total number of days.

How to write the code for this?

Comment: show what you have done so we can help on it.

Comment: After the update query do you want your data like?
250 28 Feb
100 10 Mar
700 51 Apr
Or
250 28 Feb
100 10 Mar
0 51 Apr

Comment: i have given a self join to get the sum(bill_amt) but later struck up  with the back referencing. is it possible to do this process in sql with less complexity?

Comment: @Nitesh: i dnt want to update.. i just want to find the sum of days to clear my debt

Comment: Is it ok with you to get the result using function or SP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
DECLARE @Debt AS DECIMAL
DECLARE @Days AS DECIMAL
DECLARE @Amount AS DECIMAL
DECLARE @TotalDays AS DECIMAL
SET @TotalDays = 0

SET @Debt = 700

DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT [Days], Amount FROM Test
    OPEN MyCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @Days, @Amount
    WHILE (@@Fetch_Status = 0 AND @Debt > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF(@Debt > @Amount)
            SET @TotalDays = @TotalDays + @Days
        ELSE
            SET @TotalDays = @TotalDays + (@Days * @Debt/@Amount)

        SET @Debt = @Debt - @Amount

        FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @Days, @Amount
    END

    CLOSE MyCursor
    DEALLOCATE MyCursor

SELECT @TotalDays
```

Comment: Hi prasanna, Thanks for the code.. i have a doubt.how can the "fetch next" part bring me the value for march after getting the value from april? the code has to check the value from the last month ie. april->march->feb->jan

Comment: In SELECT on cursor declaration, use ORDER BY to sort the records as you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Find the below solution using function to get the no. of days for covering the debt amount.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION GetNoOfDays  
    (    
        @debt_amt DECIMAL(14, 2) 
    ) 
    RETURNS INT  
    AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @days INT = 0
        DECLARE @amt DECIMAL(14, 2)
        DECLARE @day INT
        DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT [Days], [Amount] FROM Account ORDER BY [Month] DESC

        OPEN c1

        FETCH NEXT FROM c1 
        INTO @day, @amt

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            IF @debt_amt > @amt
            BEGIN
                SET @days = @days + @day
                SET @debt_amt = @debt_amt - @amt
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @days = @days + ROUND(@debt_amt / @amt * @day, 0)
                SET @debt_amt = 0
                BREAK
            END

            FETCH NEXT FROM c1 
            INTO @day, @amt

        END

        CLOSE c1
        DEALLOCATE c1

        RETURN @days
    END

    GO

    SELECT dbo.GetNoOfDays(700)
```

Note: please replace the Table name according to your environment. I assumed the Month column to store numeric month value like 2, 3, 4 etc. and sorted on it in desc order. for year wise data you should store the values like 201202, 201203, 201204 etc.